# How to invoke the same maven build twice in one call

Tags: maven

Is it possible to invoke the same maven build a number of times with different configuration parameters?

I have a maven build that creates a number RPMs with the rpm-maven-plugin. I pass it a variable (`environment`) which specifies which environment the RPM is targeted for: development, staging or production.

To create all RPMs for all environments, I call `mvn package -Denvironment=...` 3 times; and I'd like to simplify that. It would be great if I could call `mvn package` once, and it, in turn, would build three RPMs for all environments.

Do you see any way of doing this?

### Edit 1

So far (based on [dm3's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239786/how-to-invoke-the-same-maven-build-twice-in-one-call/7239999)), I can create three independent RPMs in one build, with the same properties. The problem now is to be able to change the `environment` property for each execution. Any suggestions?

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <!-- Default Environment -->
    <environment>development</environment>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-alpha-1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <id>package-development</id>
            <goals><goal>rpm</goal></goals>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <id>package-staging</id>
            <goals><goal>rpm</goal></goals>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <id>package-production</id>
            <goals><goal>rpm</goal></goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1-alpha-1</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>

          <configuration>
          ... VERY LONG CONFIG ...
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe the only way to achieve that during one maven execution is to bind several executions of the plugin (with different configurations) to a lifecycle phase, like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <id>test-1</id>
                    <configuration>
                        ...
                    </configuration>
                    <goals><goal>test</goal></goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <id>test-2</id>
                    <configuration>
                        ...
                    </configuration>
                    <goals><goal>test</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

You can attach this configuration to some profile triggered by one property (e.g. by `mvn package -Denvironment=all`).

Comment: The above example shows how to run the Maven Surefire plugin two times with two different configurations. This is defined in two different executions. You can do the same for any other plugin.

Comment: Great! This is very close to what I want. My only problem now is that my <configuration> section is two pages long. I can't just clone it three times. Is there any way to specify one configuration, and then execute it in three phases with different params?

Comment: I know, this is very old. Commenting to share what i know so it could be of some help for others. Use <configuration/> at plugin level (not within any execution) in your parent pom once and you can override, if needed, some parts of configuration for your specific execution using `combine.children` attribute.