# How to do 2 zips in the same maven project?

Tags: maven

I've a simple project which only do a zip file.
but I want to make 2 zips in the same maven project.

the pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration> 
            <descriptor>src/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                <finalName>name</finalName>     
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>
    </plugins>  
</build>
```

And the zip.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
    <format>tar</format>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>..\Maven_EclipseSite\target\products\.package\${prop.os32}\${prop.ws32}\${prop.arch32}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${prop.arch32}</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

After the build I've 1 zip, 1 tar and 1 tar.gz.
but I want duplicate the 3 to have 2 zip, 2 tar and 2 tar.gz, one in 32 bits and one in 64 bits.

I try to add in the pom another plugin

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/zip1.xml</descriptor>
                <finalName>name32bits</finalName>                   
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>
                    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/zip2.xml</descriptor>
                <finalName>name64bits</finalName>                   
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>

    </plugins>  
</build>
```

but only the last are generate ..
How can I do ?

thank you !
:)

-- I try add executions :
mvn assembly:assemby causes an error :
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) on project Maven_Installer: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>zip32</id>
                    <phase>assembly</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/zip32.xml</descriptor>
                        <finalName>SystemWorkbench${prop.os32}${prop.arch32}</finalName>                    
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>zip64</id>
                    <phase>assembly</phase>                     
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/zip64.xml</descriptor>
                        <finalName>SystemWorkbench${prop.os32}${prop.arch64}</finalName>                    
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>  
</build>
```

Comment: don't add two plugins, add two executions of the same plugin instead each with a different configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke the same maven build twice in one call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239786/how-to-invoke-the-same-maven-build-twice-in-one-call)

Comment: Also, you can have a single assembly descriptor if you use filtering http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html instead of duplicating zip1 and zip2.xml.

Comment: Remove `<phase>assembly</phase>` from the executions. There's not `assembly` phase in maven. Everything else looks fine.